# Fade in another logo on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently swapping a logo for smaller logo when the user scrolls down the page. At the moment it's a straight swap. However I'd like to add a nice animated fade in/out so the larger logo fades out, smaller logo fades in and vice-versa.

Here's a pen of my current attempt: http://codepen.io/abbasinho/pen/yyomrB

I've tried to adding `fadeIn` but with not joy.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    var logo = $(".lrg-logo");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500) {
            logo.removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo").fadeIn( "slow");
        } else {
            logo.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('lrg-logo').fadeIn( "slow");
        }

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: green;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: grey;
}

.lrg-logo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}

.sml-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things:

- logo must first be hidden in order to fade it in.
- fade should not happen on every scroll event, but just once when scrolltop > 500

  ```
  $(function() {
      var logo = $(".lrg-logo");
      $(window).scroll(function() {    
          var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= 500) {
        if(!logo.hasClass("sml-logo")) {
          logo.hide();
          logo.removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo").fadeIn( "slow");
        }
      } else {
        if(!logo.hasClass("lrg-logo")) {
          logo.hide();
          logo.removeClass("sml-logo").addClass('lrg-logo').fadeIn( "slow");
        }
      }

    });
  });
  ```

Comment: sorry, can't get the code highlighting to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(function() {
    var logo = $(".lrg-logo");
    var scrolling = false;
    var small = false;
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 500 && !scrolling && !small) {
            scrolling = true;
            logo.fadeOut(300);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                logo.fadeIn( 300).removeClass('lrg-logo').addClass("sml-logo");
                scrolling = false;
                small = true;
            }, 300);

        } else if(!scrolling && small) {
            scrolling = true;
            logo.fadeOut( 300);
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                logo.fadeIn( 300).removeClass('sml-logo').addClass("lrg-logo");
                scrolling = false;
                small = false;
            }, 300);
        }

    });
});
```

I have two flags. One to see if its currently animating or not. Another one to check if its small or large.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEGNbN

the code is in the link above